# mail blocked with message "Reached max queue time". Heroku, SendGrid

Tags: heroku, sendgrid

I host my rails application on Heroku and send mail with SendGrid add-on with starter plan, and it works well till 18 May.

But, these months, all mail (includes several to) blocked with message "Reached max queue time".
Anyone know what happened and how to solve.

I cannnot find information in heroku's devcenter and google.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/support-channels

thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am also facing the same issue with Sendgrid.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I signed up for the Sendgrid free plan last week and was attempting to send emails via a rails application. All test emails were blocked due to "Reached max queue time"...

There was a banner at the top that explained Sendgrid was requesting more information on me (seempingly optional).

It wasn't until I proceeded and filled out their form with more information could I proceed.

<sup>mailgun let me get set up without the b.s.</sup>

<sub>dedicated to people googling `sendgrid "max queue time"` and only finding this - hope it helps.</sub>